# How do I find an element relative to the current element

Tags: jquery

Probably easiest to show via code:

```
<form>
  <select class="some-jquery-class">...</select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form>
  <select class="some-jquery-class">...</select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form>
  <select class="some-jquery-class">...</select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then jquery that looks like:

```
$(".some-jquery-class").click(function() {
  // change the color of the submit button underneath and not any other
});
```

How do I find an element relative to the selected element?

Comment: See jQuery's tree traversal functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that using next()

```js
$('.some-jquery-class').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('input').css({color: 'red'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="some-jquery-class">...</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
<div>
  <button class="some-jquery-class">...</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
<div>
  <button class="some-jquery-class">...</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```